# OSM - show image overlay when hovering over marker

Tags: overlay, openlayers, marker

I'm using OpenStreetMap embedded in a page. Here is an example how I create markers - as a features of vector layer:

```js
  map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");
  map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

  // Define markers as "features" of the vector layer:
  var feature1 = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(14.4253353, 50.0865514).transform(epsg4326, projectTo), {
      description: 'Slovanský dům'
    }, {
      externalGraphic: 'img/locator.png',
      graphicHeight: 40, graphicWidth: 35, graphicXOffset: -17, graphicYOffset: -40
    }
  );

  var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay");
  vectorLayer.addFeatures(feature1);
```

I would like to add an overlay with image for every marker that will show up when hovering mouse pointer over the marker. Is it possible?

Comment: what is your Open Layers version? seems to be an old version
are you using that version for some specific reason? its better to use the latest

Comment: @nalm thanks for you answer. Im importing `<script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>` as it were described in some tutorial. What do you suggest to import?

Comment: i suggest the last version

`<script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is in 4.5.0 version, hope that helps

HTML elements

```
<div id="overlay">
    [image/content]
</div>
```

JS - Getting overlay

```
var container = document.getElementById('overlay');
```

JS - Adding to map

```
var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
    element: container,
    autoPan: true,
    autoPanAnimation: {
         duration: 250
    }
});
map.addOverlay(overlay);
```

JS - Setting onHover

```
var hasFeature = false
map.on('pointermove', function (evt) {
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function (feature) {
        var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
        overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
        hasFeature = true;
    });
    if (!hasFeature) {
        overlay.setPosition(undefined);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.

Comment: Is it compatible with v4.6.5?

Comment: sorry, it is, nothing changed since 4.5 there